# Design critique: db for NLP

Tags: database-design

I'm working on loading data from various sources into a db for subsequent NLP applications, and I'm wondering if I could get my db schema critiqued.

[image: DB schema]
gd_id and tc_id each stand in a many-many relationship to nyt_id.

The data will probably be used in two main ways

1. via grouping the docs by their topic_groups, and then feeding various topic_groups of docs into another software package
2. using all the docs in the db that meet some sort of filter to train a language model

I will probably also want to do a couple queries as I try to better understand the data. For instance, I'll be sorting the data into topic_groups based on metadata from the specific platforms (in particular, by using metadata like gd_id, tc_id, and subreddit), and I'll want to play with the data to get a sense for what heuristics would and would not work well, and for what natural topic_groups there might be (it'd probably be too much work to do actual topic modelling). The topic_groups I'm thinking of are topics like "politics" or "philosophy"; depending on what the data is like and what results I get, I might go for finer-grained topics.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First off, you don't have actual keys, you have *row pointers* (`id`s) and that will get in the way of producing a proper logical model.  For the moment, don't worry about artificial, internally generated numbers and focus instead on: 1. The proper hierarchy (orient top to bottom, not side by side) and 2. What defines uniqueness for each entity.